# Insert Multiple Posts from JSON Results

Tags: wp-insert-post

I am working on a custom function to insert posts from a JSON feed.  The JSON feed produces results as it should, but I am unable to get the wp_insert_post() function working properly, I assume because this is a loop of 20 results.  Any ideas?  Here is my current code:

```
function json_import() {

    $api = new Careerjet_API('en_GB') ;
    $page = 1 ; # Or from parameters.

    $result = $api->search(array(
      'keywords' => 'php developer',
      'location' => 'USA',
      'page' => $page ,
      'affid' => 'hiddenforexample',
    ));

    if ( $result->type == 'JOBS' ){
      $jobs = $result->jobs ;

      foreach( $jobs as $job ){

        $new_post = array(
          'post_title'    => $job->title,
          'post_content'  => $job->description,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_type'     => 'career',
        );

        wp_insert_post($new_post);   

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can call wp_insert_post with the second parameter set to true to return a wp_error if something goes wrong to debug. I propose a change like this:

$result = wp_insert_post($new_post,true);
if(is_wp_error($result)){
   $error_string = $result->get_error_message();
   echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p></div>';
}

Comment: That was helpful.  The error says "title, content and excerpt are empty".  However, I even added text to each variable like: 'post_title' => 'test', and still got the error.  Never had this issue before.

Comment: are  you working on the correct file? occasionally i realise i have been editing (or testing) the wrong piece of code.

Comment: yes.  i made the changes that kuchenundkakao suggested and the error messages now display.  Other changes I make, like the number of results also change.  Even if I make it 1 result, this still gets an error.  I added global $post; hoping that would help but it did not.

Comment: Ok, time for feeling stupid.  I at some point changed the $new_post variable and so the wp_insert_post($new_post) was an empty variable and I have wasted everyone's time.  That being said, this was not working earlier when it was correct, so adding the ($new_post, true) was the fix.